# Is it possible to get Role information via Hive QL?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I understand the concept of a role that Hive uses for security.  Is it possible to find this information via Hive QL using a statement like `DISPLAY ROLES`?

Bonus: Is it possible to get Hadoop user information via Hive QL?

Answer (score 6):

to view roles :
`SHOW ROLE GRANT principal_specification`

to view privilages :
`SHOW GRANT principal_specification

[ON object_type priv_level [(column_list)]]`

where :
`principal_specification

  : USER user

  | GROUP group

  | ROLE role`

For more details look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization)

Comment: It looks like I need to know what roles exist in order to use this method.  Do you know of a query that shows all of the roles?

Comment: If you didn't grant the roles to anybody then i don't know of a way to see the roles. But if you did grant it, use `show role grant user USERNAME`

Answer (score 2):

To display all roles in Cloudera Hive, use the following command:

```
SHOW ROLES;
```

Refer to Cloudera's [Sentry Service](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/sg_hive_sql.html) documentation for more SHOW statements.

Comment: `Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. getAllRoles() not implemented in Ranger HiveAuthorizer`